# Prove by Using the deﬁnition of continuity function

Tags: calculus, continuity

Could you please check my answer carefully, is it correct or any comment does it need?

Use the deﬁnition of continuity to show that $f(x) =(x)\sin(1/x)$, if $x\ne0$ and $f(x)=0$ if $x=0$

is continuous at $0$.

Deﬁnition: We say that a function $f$ is continuous at a provided that for any $ε > 0$, there exists a $δ > 0$ such that if $|x−a| < δ$ then $|f(x)−f(a)| < ε$

My answer:

first ,I did scrap work
given ε>0 , we need to find δ>o so that |x sin(1\x)-o|<ε ,whenever|x|<δ

|x sin(1\x)|=|x| |sin(1\x)|≤|x|<ε

this seem to suggest that we should make δ= ε

now ,I start my formal proof

There are two cases ,let $δ= ε$ for both cases.

In case $x=0$,

let kε > 0$,and $δ= ε$ such that if $|x−o| < δ$ then $|x−o| < ε$ and so $|f(x)−f(o)| < ε$

therefore, $f$ is continuous at $x=o$.

now in case $x ≠0$

let $ε > 0$,and $δ= ε$ such that if $|x−o| < δ$ then $|x−o| < ε$ and so $|f(x)−f(x_0)| < ε$

|(x) sin(1 /x)-(x_0) sin(1 /x_0)|=|(x) sin(1 /x)-x sin(1\x_0)+x sin(1\x_0)-(x_0)

sin(1 /x_0)| =|(x)[sin(1\x)-sin(1\x_0)]+sin(1/x_0)[x-x_0]|<|(x)| |[sin(1\x)-

sin(1\x_0)]|+|sin(1/x_0)| |[x-x_0]|

since |sin(1\x)|≤1 and |[sin(1\x)-sin(1\x_0)]|≤1

so,|(x) sin(1 /x)-(x_0) sin(1 /x_0)|<|x|+|x-x_o|

hence ,f(x) is continuous at x ≠0

Answer (score 0):

Let $x\to 0^+$. Then $\frac{1}{x}\to+\infty$, so $$x\sin\frac{1}{x}\to 0=f(0),$$ because $x\to 0$, while the sine is bounded. Similarly for $x\to 0^-$.

Using the definition we should check that $$\left|x\sin\frac{1}{x}\right|<\varepsilon,$$ whenever $|x|<\delta$ for $\delta$ suitably chosen. Observe that $$\left|x\sin\frac{1}{x}\right|\le |x|,$$ so if $|x|<\delta:=\varepsilon$, then $\bigl|f(x)-f(0)\bigr|<\varepsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

It was hard to read through your explanation since they are not in math mode.

for some $\epsilon>0$ and $|x-0|<\epsilon$ we have to show that there is some $\delta>0$ such that $|x \sin \frac 1x |< \delta$.

Note that since $\sin \theta \leq 1$, we have that  $|x \sin \frac 1x -0 | =|x| \times | \sin \frac 1x |<|x|<\epsilon$.

Comment: I did like what you did and I conclude with δ= ε

Comment: you are right :-)

Comment: @qwertyui, but you have tried to prove continuity in general. It is trivial at $0$ and the question was on continuity at $0$. At any $x_0$ it is more difficult to check.

Comment: @szw1710,yes, It is trivial at x=0, do you have any suggestion for this case?

Comment: @qwertyui Please read my answer once more.